# Почему "убожество" имеет отрицательный смысл?

Tags: этимология

> УБОЖЕСТВО, -а, ср. 1. Физический недостаток (устар.). 2. перен. Ничтожность, скудость, посредственность. Убожество мысли.

Из толкового словаря. Но ведь если разобрать слово - у-богий, у-божество.
Т.е. буквально, "у Бога", "у Божества". По идее как раз наоборот это слово должно значить роскошь и достаток.
А так получается, что "у Бога" скудно?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Счастье, богатство  в индоевропейском языке назывались словами bhag, bhagas. Со временем всю полноту бытия человек стал связывать с Богом, отождествляя эти понятия, называя их одинаковыми словами. Теперь богатство мыслилось как полученное извне, богатый – это щедро одаренный Богом (от глагола  bhaj, bhajati - делить, разделять, наделять).

А УБОГИЙ – это удаленный от бога и богатства, именно такое значение имеет приставка У (движение в сторону, прочь).  Слово известно в языке с 11 века: убогъ, убогый, убожьство.

Comment: Для полноты картины следовало привести примеры: убывать, угонять, убирать, уходить. А так ответ, конечно, наиболее убедительный.

Answer (score 2):

"Убогим" могли называть человека не от мира сего. Таких на Руси почитали (как юродивых), считали, что они ближе к Господу, раз освобождены от "мирского" рассудка.